# Jquery custom carousel throwing error (only in IE) after certain amount of loops

Tags: jquery

Got these functions which are just part of simple slideshow. After some 100 repeats it throws an Stack overflow (IE6) or out of memory (IE 7-8)...

Don't see anything wrong here really...Any ideas?

```
function show($itemNumber) {
                $("#mainImage").stop();
                $("#mainImage").fadeOut(fadingSpeed, function() {
                    $("#mainImage").unbind('load');
                    $("#mainImage").load(function() {
                        $("#mainImage").fadeIn(fadingSpeed);
                    });
                    $("#mainImage").attr('src',items[$itemNumber].img);
                    $("#mainText").html(items[$itemNumber].text);

                    currentItem = $itemNumber;
                });
                return false;
            }

            function moveOneSlide() {
                if (slideshow === true) {
                    currentItem++;
                    if (currentItem >= items.length) {
                        currentItem = 0;
                    }
                    setTimeout(moveOneSlide, interval);
                    show(currentItem);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked this but upto 1115 images, i did't get any errors this is the code i checked.

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var items = [{'img':'smiles/1.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/2.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/3.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/4.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/5.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/6.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/7.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/8.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/9.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/10.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/11.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/12.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/13.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/14.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/15.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/16.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/17.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/18.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/19.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/20.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/21.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/22.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/23.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/24.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/25.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/26.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/27.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/28.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/29.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/30.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/31.gif','text':'hello'},                                
             {'img':'smiles/32.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/33.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/34.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/35.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/36.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/37.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/38.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/39.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/41.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/42.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/43.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/44.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/45.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/46.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/47.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/48.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/49.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/50.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/51.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/52.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/53.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/54.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/55.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/56.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/57.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/58.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/59.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/60.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/61.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/62.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/63.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/64.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/65.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/66.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/67.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/68.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/79.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/70.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/71.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/72.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/73.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/74.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/75.gif','text':'hi'},
             {'img':'smiles/76.gif','text':'hello'},
             {'img':'smiles/77.gif','text':'hi'}];
```

next

```
                fadingSpeed=10;
                interval=1000;
                currentItem=0;
                count='0'
            function show($itemNumber) {
                count++;
                //$("#mainImage").stop();
                $("#mainImage").fadeOut(fadingSpeed, function() {
                    $("#mainImage").unbind('load');
                    $("#mainImage").load(function() {
                        $("#mainImage").fadeIn(fadingSpeed);
                    });
                    $("#mainImage").attr('src',items[$itemNumber].img);
                    $("#mainText").html(items[$itemNumber].text);
                    $("#mainNum").html(count)
                    currentItem = $itemNumber;
                });
                return false;
            }

            function moveOneSlide() {
                    currentItem++;
                    if (currentItem >= items.length) {
                        currentItem = 0;
                    }
                    setTimeout(moveOneSlide, interval);
                    show(currentItem);
                    }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                moveOneSlide();
            });
            </script>
```

html

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<img src="" id='mainImage'>
<div id='mainText'></div> 
<div id='mainNum'></div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating several functions every call here. Consider moving them out of the loop and set them via the named variable to lower memory usage. Additionally, are you showing us your whole function? There's no recursion going on there; it seems like you're setting it up with the `moveOneSlide()` function, but in your code it's not being called. Make sure you posted all of the relevant code.